# Why does 1GB disk show as 1073MB and not 1024MB?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, storage

`fdisk -l` output snippet showing disk `/dev/sdd` of **1GB** size:

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdd: 1073 MB, 1073741824 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 130 cylinders Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier: 0x8bd61ee2

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sdd1 1 130 1044193+ 83 Linux LVM
```

Comment: 1073 MB == 1 GiB (approximately).  Who's telling you the disk is 1 GB?

Comment: 1073741824 bytes = 1048576 KiB = 1024 MiB = 1 GiB. That's dividing by 1024 on each step. If you divide by 1000 instead, you get 1073741824 bytes = 1073741.8 KB = 1073.7 MB = 1.07 GB. Perhaps you're confusing the two sets of units?